# Trying to display images uploaded to database

Tags: php, sql, photo, photos

I am trying to upload photos to aa database that saves them to an images folder in my project folder.  The photos dont display when I upload them, nor do they save to a folder.

my process.php is this

```
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES["picture"]["tmp_name"])) {
$filename = uniqid("image") . ".jpg"; 
copy($_FILES["picture"]["tmp_name"],"images/" . $filename);
} else {
$errormessage = $errormessage . "Image is required <br />";
}
```

my form.php is this

```
<?php
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {

echo "<tr><td>" . $row["title"] . "</td><td>" . $row["description"] . "</td><td>" . $row["price"] . "</td><td>" . $row["category"] . "</td>";
echo "<img src='images/" . $row["picture"] . "' width='300'>";
echo "<td><a href='admin_menu_edit.php?id=" . $row["id"] . "'>edit</a> ";
echo "<a href='admin_menu_delete.php?id=" . $row["id"] . "'>delete</a> </td>";

echo"</tr>";
}
```

all I see is a broken link square where the image should be.  I even tried copying the generated filename and inserting it into my images folder manually and it still did not display a thing.  I am lost.

Comment: You uploaded an image and stored a reference to it in the database? Can you show us *that* code?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the function

[`move_uploaded_file ( string $filename , string $destination )`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)

instead of `copy`

```
$filename = uniqid("image") . ".jpg"; 
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["picture"]["tmp_name"],"images/" . $filename);
```

For more information, see http://davidwalsh.name/basic-file-uploading-php

Comment: I am in an intro class and havent heard of this function before...how would I implement that?

Comment: i tried implementing the code you gave, but it still doesnt put the images into my images folder. ty  for your time though

Comment: does the images directory exist?  try using the full path to the images directory, rather than the relative path.  make sure your webserver has permissions to write to that folder.

Comment: how do i give permissions to mysql to do so

Comment: it's not mysql, its your webserver, most likely apache.  If you are running it on Linux you would do, from the commandline, something like "sudo chgrp apache /path/to/upload/folder" and then "sudo chmod 775 /path/to/upload/folder".  If you're on windows then I have no idea.